# How do I numerically compute the interquark potential from the correlation function of Polyakov Loops?

Tags: potential, correlation-functions, quarks, wilson-loop, lattice-gauge-theory

I know that the potential can be calculated in the following way:

$$
aV(r) =-\ln(<\sum_{\textbf{x}} (P(\textbf{x}+R)P^{\dagger}(\textbf{x}))>)/N_T.
$$

Now, suppone I have some procudure to numerically compute the argument of the logarithm. For general $SU(N)$ theories, that quantity is going to be a complex number, since it is just a product of traces of products of $SU(N)$ matrices. How do I extract the potential from that? Do I take the module of that quantity?